# slash and wp_register_style

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I came across a weird situation about WordPress and need a help.

- WordPress 4.9.8
- PHP 7.2.8
- MySQL 5.7

I am making a theme for my WordPress site and trying to apply app.css.
Below is my script in functions.php to register app.css.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',function(){
    wp_register_style('app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/app.css', array(), '20170313', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('app');
});
```

In theme customizer or live preview screen, this app.css is applied and no problem.

[customizer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX7hu.jpg)

I checked chrome developer tool and found link element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="app-css" href="https://bunborg.74th.net/wp-content/themes/mogami74_bunborg/css/app.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

But when I activate the theme and watched the blog, app.css is not applied at all.  I cannot find link element by developer tool.

Strange enough, I noticed link element appear when I erased the first slash of the '/css/app.css',  but of course href attribute is bloken.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',function(){
    wp_register_style('app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/app.css', array(), '20170313', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('app');
});

<link rel="stylesheet" id="app-css" href="https://bunborg.74th.net/wp-content/themes/mogami74_bunborgcss/app.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I also tried,

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',function(){
    wp_register_style('app','/wp- content/themes/mogami74_bunborg/css/app.css',array(),'20170313','all');
    wp_enqueue_style('app');
});
```

The same result.
'/wp- content/themes/mogami74_bunborg/css/app.css' results no link element, while 'wp- content/themes/mogami74_bunborg/css/app.css' results link element but broken href attribute.

I wonder why adding '/' fails to enqueue script.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

### 2018-09-03 additional info

My theme directory contains

```
archive.php  
comments.php  
css/  
footer.php  
functions.php  
header-archive.php  
header-single.php  
header.php  
index.php  
loop-archive.php  
loop-justpurchased.php  
loop.php  
README.md  
SCSS/  
sidebar.php  
single.php  
style.css
```

Comment: Have you tried using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`? Keep the slash in the string `/css/app.css`. You can also remove the `wp_register_style` and just do `wp_enqueue_style( 'app', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/app.css', array(), '20180830', 'all' );`

Comment: I tried but the same result.  with slash no link element, without slash href broken.

Comment: What is the structure of your theme? There must be an error somewhere. I'm assuming you have your `Theme-directory > functions.php and style.css` at a minimum.

Comment: I added files in my theme directory.  

I wonder why adding '/' fails to enqueue script.  I checked inside function wp_enqueue_style() but found no reason to reject '/' ...